# Nonlinear discrete and continuous optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

I'm trying to minimize a cost function that is made up of dependent binary variables and continuous variables.

For example the cost function could look like:

$F(x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, r_{0}, r_{1}) = 0.8x_{0} + 0.2x_{0}x_{1} + 0.7 x_{2}r_{1} + 0.4 x_{1}x_{2}r_{1} + 0.3 x_{1} + 0.2 r_{0} + 0.3 x_{1}r_{1}$

subject the constraints that $\sqrt{r_{0}^{2}+r_{1}^{2}}=1$, $r_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$ and  $x_{i}\in \{-1,+1\}$.

In general, there can be many $x_{i}$ and $r_{i}$ terms, where $\vec{r}$ needs to be a normalized vector and at most only one component of $\vec{r}$ can contribute to each term in the sum. Whereas, many $x_{i}$ can occur in a term (but without repeats).

What is the best approach to solve this minimization problem?

Currently, I brute force assign all possible binary assignments of the $x_{i}$ variables and then solve the convex problem for $r_{0}$ and $r_{1}$. This works in small cases, but clearly will not scale.

Could a Second-order cone program be used? But this would require  linearization techniques, which seems possible ([Nonlinear Binary Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995483/nonlinear-binary-programming))

Comment: I don't see a second order cone problem here, because the projection of your feasible region onto the $r$ variables (the unit sphere in $r$ space, rather than the unit ball) is nonconvex.